# clarifying rails find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I call the rails `find` method a lot during my view. Is this a generally accepted good practice? I'm leaning towards no, but why? Does `find` call the database each time? Does it cache the result anywhere? I looked up the ruby/rails docs on `find` but they didn't specify if it actually made a call to the database each time or not.

Comment: This is not a Good question.. put a simple example to let us know what made you confused...not the whole code...

Comment: i took the code out, i'm not confused about anything, i'm asking specific questions about the .find() method.  1. can you include it in the view (is it good practice) 2. does it make a call to the database each time?

Comment: the code was only there to show where I was using it (the view) and how many times I had to use it (a lot) which supports the questions I am asking, rather than asking a question about the code @ArupRakshit

Comment: Why do you call it `ruby's method`? It's `rails's` or more specifically -- `activerecord's`

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev my mistake, sorry about that.  i get confused what belongs to what language/platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a good idea to call `find` from the view. It is the job of a controller to load and assemble all the data that a view will need, and pass it to the view for presentation to the user.

Repeated calls to `find` for the same object should be cached by Rails, so it wouldn't hit the database each time, unless the arguments or other parameters were different.

Answer (score 0):

A realtively easy way to test this would be to fire up a terminal and run `rails c`.  In the console, run the code that returns `tplangroup` and play with it in the console.  You should be able to see database call in the development console.

Based on my experience (not at a computer with rails right now) I think it would hit the database in each of these calls, unless you created `tplangroup` using the `.includes(:tplan)` for eager loading.

Hope this helps